# trying to find if certain characters are present in an id

Tags: jquery

```
<span class="help-block" style="color:red;text-align:left;" id="1012Error">Error Block</span>
<span class="help-block" style="color:red;text-align:left;" id="1013">Clear</span>
<span class="help-block" style="color:red;text-align:left;" id="1012Error">Error Block</span>
<span class="help-block" style="color:red;text-align:left;" id="1012">Clear</span>
```

am trying to achieve something like this

```
if(id contains "error")
{
  $(this).html("");
}
```

can someone guide me how to get this

Comment: You should consider using something other than parts of an ID to indicate error status, like a class or data- attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery features [selectors that can be used to target specific elements based on their attributes](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). In this case, there are two that you could use in this scenario.

**The Ends With Selector `$=`**

You could find any elements having attributes that end-with a specific phrase using [`$=` attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) through the following syntax:

```
// This will empty the HTML for any element that has an ID that ends with "Error" 
$('[id$="Error"]').html('');
```

**The Contains Selector `*=`**

Similarly, the [`*=` attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) will find any elements that have a certain attribute that "contains" a specific value:

```
$('[id*="Error"]').html('');
```

**Handle Multiple Operations via `each()`**

If you needed to perform multiple operations for your elements, you could use the [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to iterate through them and handle your operations :

```
// Find each element that ends with "Error"...
$('[id*="Error"]').each(function(){
     // And clear it out
     $(this).html('');
     // Then do something else here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('span[id*="Error"]').html('')
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hu7nh2kp/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
$('span.help-block').each(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   # test if it matches error
   if(id.match(/error/i)){
     # your operation here
     $(this).text(""); // for example
   }
})
```